# MySQL Select top lap times while grouped by user

Tags: mysql

I have a simple MySQL Table for lap times.
Made up of the following

- Primay Key
- Track ID
- Users ID
- Lap Time
- Lap Status

I basically want to select the top 10 lap times, but only one per user.
So if I have 2 lap times for X track, I want to get the best one.

If I run

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_lap_times ORDER BY lap_times ASC
```

I see both my lap times, with my best time at the top.
But as mentioned, I only want one lap time per user.

If I run

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_lap_times GROUP BY users_id ORDER BY lap_times ASC
```

Then i get my first lap time, (which is not my best lap time)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to aggregate using `MIN`. Something like this should work (untested):

```
SELECT user_id, track_id, lap_status, MIN(lap_times) AS best_time
FROM tbl_lap_times
GROUP BY user_id, track_id, lap_status
ORDER BY best_time DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `min()` function?

`SELECT users_id, min(lap_times) FROM tbl_lap_times GROUP BY users_id`