# mySQL - select the top n rows, grouped by 2 columns

Tags: mysql, database

I've found existing questions with the latest/lowest single row over several fields, or latest n rows over a single field, but not the two together

I need to construct 2 queries, using this example table (similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289811/mysql-select-top-lap-times-while-grouped-by-user))

```
CREATE TABLE lap_data (
     id            int(1)     NOT NULL,
     track_id      int(1)     NOT NULL,
     user_id       int(1)     NOT NULL,
     lap_time      time       NOT NULL,
     lap_status    tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

```
INSERT INTO `lap_data` (`id`, `track_id`, `user_id`, `lap_time`, `lap_status`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, '04:18:23', 1),
(2, 2, 2, '01:09:54', 1),
(3, 2, 1, '01:05:30', 1),
(4, 1, 2, '04:17:02', 1),
(5, 3, 2, '01:13:10', 1),
(6, 4, 1, '01:36:59', 0),
(7, 3, 2, '01:18:10', 1),
(8, 2, 3, '01:06:42', 1),
(9, 1, 1, '04:16:12', 1),
(10, 1, 2, '04:18:12', 1),
(11, 2, 3, '01:03:20', 1),
(12, 2, 1, '01:08:13', 1),
(13, 2, 1, '01:09:44', 1),
(14, 3, 2, '01:14:10', 1),
(15, 3, 2, '01:17:20', 1),
(16, 4, 1, '01:36:23', 1),
(17, 2, 1, '01:11:34', 1);
```

**Query 1:**

- I want the top 2 results by lap_time - per track, per user

  - so if a given user_id has 20 records spread over 3 tracks...

    - I would expect 6 results for that user_id
    - or 5 if one of those tracks only has a single record
  - the same lap time at 2 different tracks should both be displayed, not appear just once
- I want to use a WHERE user_id IN (..) for part 1
- ordered by a given field, ie lap_time
- where lap_status = 1

This is the query I've been using elsewhere to collect the two latest records of a given type, which is the closest to what I think I need, modified to this example .. although unfinished, as in the other instance, it was only collecting the 2 most recent rows for each user_id .. here I need it to take track_id into account as well

```
 SELECT
 * 
 FROM (
     SELECT
     t.id,
     t.track_id,
     t.user_id,
     t.lap_time,
     t.lap_status,
     @row:=case WHEN @prev=user_id THEN @row ELSE 0 END +1 rn,
     @prev:=user_id
     FROM `lap_data` t
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row:=0, @prev:=null) c
     WHERE t.user_id IN (1,2)
     ORDER BY user_id, id DESC
 ) src
 WHERE rn <= 2
 ORDER BY lap_time DESC
```

**Query 1 Desired result:**  ( WHERE user_id IN (1,2) )

```
|  id  |  track_id  |  user_id  |  lap_time  |  lap_status  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   9  |         1  |        1  |  04:16:12  |           1  |
|   1  |         1  |        1  |  04:18:23  |           1  |
|   3  |         2  |        1  |  01:05:30  |           1  |
|  12  |         2  |        1  |  01:08:13  |           1  |
|  16  |         4  |        1  |  01:36:23  |           1  |
|   6  |         4  |        1  |  01:36:59  |           1  |
|   4  |         1  |        2  |  04:17:02  |           1  |
|  10  |         1  |        2  |  04:18:12  |           1  |
|   2  |         2  |        2  |  01:09:54  |           1  |
|   5  |         3  |        2  |  01:13:10  |           1  |
|  14  |         3  |        2  |  01:14:10  |           1  |
```

**Query 2:**

- I want to get the inverse of the above, for a single user

  - ie the remainder of the results excluding the first two, for just a specific user_id

**Query 2 Desired result:**  ( WHERE user_id = '1' )

```
|  id  |  track_id  |  user_id  |  lap_time  |  lap_status  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  13  |         2  |        1  |  01:09:44  |           1  |
|  17  |         2  |        1  |  01:11:34  |           1  |
```

Any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Strawberry added info guys, thanks for prompting me

Comment: Your effort looks very close- are you sure you can't figure out how to adapt that?

Comment: Query 2 Desired result => I could not found lap_time ( 01:11:34) map with user_id(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MYSQL Version for my previous answer:

```
SELECT 
lt.id,
lt.user_id,
lt.track_id,
lt.lap_status,
lt.lap_time 
FROM (
SELECT id,
    user_id,
    track_id,
    lap_status,
    lap_time,
    CASE WHEN track_id = @prevTrackId AND user_id = @prevUserId THEN @curRank := @curRank + 1 ELSE @curRank := 1 END Rank,
    @prevTrackId := track_id,
    @prevUserId := user_id
FROM lap_data, (SELECT @curRank := 0, @prevTrackId := 1, @prevUserId := 1) r
ORDER BY user_id,track_id,lap_time ASC
) lt 
WHERE Rank <= 2
```

Comment: thanks for posting another version .. unfortunately this returns 4 rows for user_id=1 and track_id=2

Comment: Okay, i forgot to assign the prevTrackId and prevUserId to current row. Try out the edited code above.

Comment: I'm still checking against various use cases, but this looks like it does the job...thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

This query makes one important (and quite likely erroneous) assumption - which is that the highest track_id of the previous user is higher than (or at least different from) the lowest track_id of the following user.

If that's not the case, then you may need to store another variable, or base 'prev' on the concatenation of two values...

```
 SELECT x.id
      , x.track_id 
      , x.user_id 
      , x.lap_time 
      , x.lap_status 
   FROM 
      ( SELECT l.*
             , CASE WHEN @prev = track_id THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END rank
             , @prev:=track_id prev 
          FROM lap_data l
             , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
         WHERE user_id IN(1,2) 
         ORDER 
            BY user_id
             , track_id
             , lap_time
      ) x
  WHERE x.rank <=2
  ORDER 
     BY user_id
      , track_id
      , lap_time;
```

Comment: Thank you for this.. the track_id could be the same or different unfortunately, ie could have multiple users all with records for only track 2, for instance... Between storing another value and concatenating both into prev, which is likely to be quickest?

Comment: An extra variable is better, regardless - but I find it this logic easier to write as nested IFs, rather than nested CASE statements

Comment: Could I trouble you to post the query with two fields as user defined values? I have no idea how to approach it ..... (I'm actually stunned I managed to correctly guess that either prev needed to be concatenated, or track two fields)

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,track_id,user_id,lap_status,lap_time from (
select @rank:=if(@prev_cat=user_id,@rank+1,1) as rank,id,user_id,track_id,lap_status,lap_time,@prev_cat:=user_id
from lap_data,(select @rank:=0, @prev_cat:="")t
where user_id IN(1,2) order by track_id, user_id desc
  ) temp
  where temp.rank<=2
```

Comment: this returns four rows with track_id=2 and user_id=1 .. i only wanted two rows

Answer (score -1):

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT lt.id,lt.user_id,lt.track_id,lt.lap_status,lt.lap_time 
FROM (
    SELECT id,user_id,track_id,lap_status,lap_time,Rank() 
    over (Partition BY user_id,track_id
    ORDER BY lap_time ASC ) AS Rank
    FROM lap_data
    WHERE user_id IN (1,2)
) lt WHERE Rank <= 2
```

**Query 2:**
Simply just select all records which `NOT IN` Query 1. (assuming id is the primary key of your table, which you did not even set a primary key for lap_data table)

```
SELECT * FROM lap_data
    WHERE id NOT IN
    (SELECT lt.id 
    FROM (
        SELECT id,Rank() 
        over (Partition BY user_id,track_id
        ORDER BY lap_time ASC ) AS Rank
        FROM lap_data
        WHERE user_id = 1
    ) lt WHERE Rank <= 2)
```

Comment: thanks unfortunately i get an error on the first query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(Partition BY user_id,track_id ORDER BY lap_time ASC ) AS Rank FROM la' at line 4

Comment: Ha, sorry, i provided the solution in MSSQL instead of MySQL, my bad.